How to make a background tab run callbacks?
I have a JS app that shouldn't run if the tab runs in the background (i.e, it isn't focused). But many components of that app rely on a timer, which I therefore must stop while the tab isn't active. So I did something like :
let now = () => window.performance.now()
let lastUpdate = now()
let ellapsed = 0

window.setInterval(() => {
    let t = now()
    if (!document.hidden) ellapsed += t - lastUpdate
    lastUpdate = t
})


The problem is : if the tab isn't focused, setInterval being low-priority and thus not called often when running in background, when coming back to the tab, up to 1 second could have passed since last time lastUpdate was... well, updated, resulting in the program thinking the user spent one whole second on the page even though they just jumped back onto it, and wrongly incrementing ellapsed accordingly.
My question is : how can I force JS to call that function very often even if the tab is a background tab ?
I know this is a bad practice, but the callback is reaaally small, and it's the only thing I want to call very frequently precisely because it allows the rest of the application to pause correctly.
Thanks !

You need to use javascript Web workers for this... Refer to the following documentation
Mozilla

That sounds a bit like an xy-problem. It probably would make sense to explain what purpose those timers have and how the behavior of your components should change depending on if the app is in the background or foreground and when the state changes.

Instead of only relying on document.hidden in the setInterval callback, you can add an event listener that is triggered whenever the visiblity state changes:
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  console.log(document.hidden);
});

Based on that you can update your lastUpdate, elapsed, and start and stop your interval.
